# How to edit Big Cartel code to make home button all on one line

Tags: css, bigcartel

I'm new to this site and have never posted a question online before, so I apologise if my question isn't formatted correctly.

I use Big Cartel to host my online store, and I am wondering how to edit the CSS in order to make the home button text (at the top left of the site) appear on a single line. It used to be, but I changed the font, and all fonts asides from the original force the text ("NOT ENOUGH KNIFE") to appear on two separate lines.

I have edited CSS several times to add a favicon and remove Big Cartel branding. However, I am not sure how to do this.

My site is here: http://www.NotEnoughKnife.store

As you can see, the text "NOT ENOUGH KNIFE" at the top left appears on two lines. How do I edit the CSS to make it appear on a single line?

I am using the 'neat' theme.

Thankyou for any help,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can modify the CSS you can add  `white-space: nowrap` to the `header .logo a` selector.

see the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Perfect, thankyou very much. It took me a minute to find "header .logo a" within Big Cartel's CSS editor, but I couldn't have done it without you. thanks again.